# Connecting to a domain to determine if a server is online using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need to attempt to make a connection to a domain to determine whether a specific server is online

i have tried to use socket to create a connection but it never makes a connection even though the domain is online

```py
import socket


def ConnectionTest():
    domain = "www.something.com/uptimecheck"

    try:
        socket.create_connection((domain, 443))
        return True
    except OSError:
        pass
    return False
```

even when i know the domain is online the connection test always returns False, when in theory it should return true.

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting the server on 443, that means you're just checking on a TCP socket with the application layer protocol being HTTPS i.e. the remote end socket tuple is `(<server_ip>, 443)`.

So you can get away with using a typical web client e.g. `requests` is one (install it with `pip install requests`, if not done already):

```
import requests

def is_online(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.status_code == 200
```

Now, you can do:

```
url = "https://www.something.com/uptimecheck"
url_is_online = is_online(url)
```

Notice that I've prepended the protocol (`https`) to the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

The address you're using must resolve into an IP address in order to be able to use it with `socket`, so you need to use only the domain address and port (without the path `/uptimecheck`):

```py
import socket


def test_alive(domain: str, port: int):
    try:
        with socket.create_connection((domain, port)) as s:
            return True
    except OSError:
        pass
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    domain = "example.com"
    print(test_alive(domain, port=443))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only to test if URL exists and server is sending some response, it can be any code even 500 as well

```
try:
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
    p_response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

    print(True)
except:
    print(False)
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use `p_response.raise_for_status()` to handle 400+ status codes. This code will report `True` even when server is dead and returns 500 responses, for example.

Comment: No it will return true for < 300

Comment: try it with `res = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/status/500')` without checking for status code, what do you get?